# Soft hyphen in Microsoft Word (Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-word, layout, microsoft-word-365, typography

I fail to insert a soft hyphen in Microsoft Word with `CTRL + -` since some time now. All it does is changing the zoom level instead of inserting a soft hyphen.

Searching the web did not help much, because most of the help pages I found refer to use `CTRL + -`.

Answer (score 0):

What helped was to assign `CTRL + -` to insert a soft hypen again.

Menu bar: Insert > Menu Group: Symbols > Menu item: Symbol > Submenu item: More symbols

[image]

Tab: "Special Chracters" > List item: "Optional Hyphen" > Button "Shortcut Key..."

[image]

Input field: "Press new shortcut key"

[image]

Now adding a soft hyphen is super easy again.